# Does Windows7 uses WPF?

Tags: wpf, windows-7

In Windows 7 (and Vista) is WPF used for the taskbar, the widgets, explorer or for anything else of the OS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The Windows Explorer doesn't use it, none of Windows built-in utilities use it, Office 2007 doesn't use it... AFAIK, the only MS app that uses WPF so far is the upcoming Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

I know that WPF is not used in the Explorer shell (I recall a blog post by Raymond Chen saying that .NET shouldn't be used in Explorer, but I can't recall for sure). I don't think it's used in any of the other utility apps that ship with Windows 7, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Don't do Shell Extension Handlers in .NET: http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2005/11/18/494572.aspx